# How to write this crawler in php?

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing, web-crawler

I need to create a **php script**.

The idea is very simple:

When I send a link of a blogpost to this php script, then the webpage is crawled and **the first image with the title page** are saved on my server.

What **PHP function** I have to use for this crawler ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// Find all images
$images = array(); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
       $images[] = $element->src;
}
```

Now `$images` array have images links of given webpage. Now you can store your desired image in database.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Parser: [HTMLSQL](http://www.jonasjohn.de/lab/htmlsql.htm)

Features: you can get external html file, http or ftp link and parse content.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll have to use quite a few functions :)

But I'm going to assume that you're asking specifically about finding the image, and say that you should use a DOM parser like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), then curl to grab the src of the first img element.

Answer (score 1):

I would user [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and a regular expression to extract the first image tags `src` attribute.

[CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or a HTML Parser seem overkill in this case, but you are welcome to check it out.

Comment: `CURL` is faster than `file_get_contents()`